# Trying to pass function callbacks - callbacks don't execute correctly

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a piece of code that essentially listens to the accelerometer and gyroscope and does some operations. The code works perfectly well, but today, I tried splitting this function into two halves:

- The listening part was moved to service (sensors.ts)
- The "act on data receive part" was moved to the calling ts file.

<s>I'm facing an issue with the fact that if I am doing any operation in the callback that might take some time, I'm not getting subsequent callbacks.</s>

I'm facing an issue where my callback is indeed invoked, but calling other functions inside my called back code are resulting in the app just getting "stuck" (no further updates to subscription received)

Here is the code:

In **sensors.ts**

`type SensorCallbackFunction = (data:any) => void;`

Note (I also tried using `Function` instead of the above type)

```
startAllSensors(onAccData:SensorCallbackFunction, onGyroData:SensorCallbackFunction) {
    // listen to acc. data
    this.accSub = this.deviceMotion.watchAcceleration({ frequency: this.freq }).subscribe((acceleration: DeviceMotionAccelerationData) => {
      console.log (">>>>>>>>>>>>> ACC CALLBACK")
      onAccData(acceleration); 

    });

    // listen to gyro data
    this.gyrSub = this.gyroscope.watch({ frequency: this.freq })
      .subscribe((gyroscope: GyroscopeOrientation) => {
        console.log (">>>>>>>>>>>>> GYR CALLBACK")
       onGyroData(gyroscope);

      });

  }
```

In the component that calls this service:

```
 this.sensors.startAllSensors(this.accDataReceived, this.gyroDataReceived);
```

And the functions in the component:

```
accDataReceived(data) {

    console.log ("acc data:"+JSON.stringify(data));
}

gyroDataReceived(data) {

    console.log ("gyr data:"+JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

**this works well**

<s>But the moment I extend the functionality of either callback I stop getting subsequent notifications (that is, these callbacks are not called by the service).</s>

But the moment I extend the functionality of either callback to invoke additional functions I stop getting subsequent notifications (that is, these callbacks are not called by the service)

For example, I just added this code to both callbacks:

```
let dataClone = data.map(x => Object.assign({}, x));
this.doMoreStuff();
```

And boom, I stopped getting subscription updates. I also tried calling another function that plots a chart inside them and I have the same problem.

This makes me believe I am somehow misunderstanding how function callbacks should work and what the expectations are in the code that goes into callbacks.

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you adding the code to the callbacks?

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly. The callbacks are "accDataReceived" and "gyroDataReceived". The code is being added there. Thanks.

Comment: Could you build a plunker that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: I'm sorry, I misidentified the issue. I've added edits on what is really going on, and found the reason for it too - will post an answer too. The problem basically was when the service is calling a callback, `this` belongs to the service, so component function calls were undefined due to this problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, it was a problem with `this`. I misidentified the root cause.

- `Component A` was calling a function on `Service S` with a callback `this.componentACallback`
- `Service S` correctly called the function `componentACallback` as needed
- `componentACallback` inside `Component A` in turn, was doing more processing by calling `this.doSomeOtherComponentAFunction()`

This is where things broke

`this` was now pointing to `Service S` (the caller) and therefore `this.doSomeOtherComponentAFunction()` was invalid.

Why this did not return an error, and why it messed up other operations, such as simple `console.logs` within `componentACallback` is unknown - all I can guess is it messed up some state stack somewhere...

Anyway, the fix therefore was to `bind` `this` when passing the callback reference like so:

`this.ServiceS.serviceSFunction(this.componentACallback.bind(this))` instead of 
`this.ServiceS.serviceSFunction(this.componentACallback)`